# create custom exceptions in java without exception class?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, error-handling, runtimeexception

create custom exceptions in java without exception class is it possible?

even if i have write required classes and interfaces for new class and extend that class to create custom Exception?

Answer (score 0):

What would your `Exception` be in this case? To name something as `Exception` in Java, you need to inherit from Java `Exception` class. I don't see any other possibility. If you need to throw something if certain circumstances happen, it needs to be inherited from `Exception` class - no matter if it is your own created `Exception` class or if it is any of built-in Java `Exception` classes.